# Error says "Could not find a required file. Name: index.js"

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I'm trying to deploy my backend server into heroku but each time I do it, I keep getting an application error. And when I went to the log to check what went wrong, my git says it cannot find index.js.

I tried to fix it by moving my index.js into a public folder and changing my main entry point from `index.js` to `public/index.js` in my `package.json`, but it still wouldn't find the file. What is it I am doing wrong?

Here is the error I am getting

```
2021-04-15T20:19:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-15T20:19:18.661041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-15T20:19:22.775555+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-15T20:19:22.775583+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-04-15T20:19:22.775584+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2021-04-15T20:19:22.775584+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-15T20:19:25.621087+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not find a required file.
2021-04-15T20:19:25.621968+00:00 app[web.1]: Name: index.js
2021-04-15T20:19:25.622086+00:00 app[web.1]: Searched in: /app/src
2021-04-15T20:19:25.646722+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-15T20:19:25.647156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-04-15T20:19:25.655186+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2021-04-15T20:19:25.655413+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-04-15T20:19:25.655603+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-15T20:19:25.655751+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
2021-04-15T20:19:25.655898+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-15T20:19:25.664579+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-15T20:19:25.664850+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-15T20:19:25.664960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-15T20_19_25_656Z-debug.log
2021-04-15T20:19:25.726536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-15T20:19:25.802980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Share your package.json file.

Comment: @Lovekesh Kumar https://github.com/AmmanMeb/Forum/blob/main/server/package.json

Comment: I also edited my post to show the package.json file